# Django channels, UserWarning: async_to_sync was passed a non-async-marked callable

Tags: python, django, django-channels, asgi

I am using Django channels for the notification system,i want to send a notification to the associated store when an order is created, i create Notification model to save all previous notifications and in my post_save order signal i create notification instance.
I'm using `WebsocketConsumer` customer type, without any authentication 'for know'.

`consumers.py`

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


class StoreConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.store_slug = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['store_slug']
        self.store_group_name = f'store_{self.store_slug}'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.store_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
      pass
    def send_notification(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        self.send(text_data=message)
```

`notification_signals.py`

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from stores.models import Notification
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def send_notification(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print('channel_layer > > ',channel_layer)
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        f'store_{instance.store.id}',
        {
            'type': 'store_notification',
            'message': instance.message
        }
    )
```

`asgi.py`

```py
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from stores.urls import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'neo.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        ),
    )
})

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

- Every time i run my dev server i got this error:

```bash
      UserWarning: async_to_sync was passed a non-async-marked callable
```

- I try to use 'AsyncWebsocketConsumer' channels customer type.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_3.html

But i got the same promlem

Comment: Hi, please consider narrowing your question down to the core of the problem. There are many superfluous pieces of code. This would not be helpful to other readers of the site or even someone trying to answer your question.